# How to have where clause on row_number within the same select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row-number

I'm not able to use where condition on the row number within the same select statement. Results are not consistent if I use a different select statement for applying condition over the rownumber...

```
 SELECT TOP (@lastrow - 1) c.totalRows
        ,c.ae_effective_enrollment_id
        ,c.[user_id]
        ,c.login_name
        ,c.first_name
        ,c.last_name
        ,cm.courseware_title
        ,cm.courseware_code
        ,@courseware_id assetId
        ,c.enrollment_status_id
        ,CASE 
            WHEN c.enrollment_status_id = 2
                AND c.is_self_enrolled = 0
                THEN 'Admin-' + s.description
            WHEN c.enrollment_status_id = 2
                AND c.is_self_enrolled = 1
                THEN 'Self-' + s.description
            ELSE s.description
            END AS enrollmentStatus
        ,c.is_group
        ,CASE 
            WHEN c.is_self_enrolled = 0
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END is_admin
        ,CASE 
            WHEN c.auma_is_assigned = 1
                THEN 'Admin-assigned'
            WHEN c.auma_is_assigned = 0
                THEN 'Self-assigned'
            ELSE 'No-My-Plan'
            END AS myplanStatus
        , master_assignment_id
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by cm.courseware_id,c.user_id order by c.is_self_enrolled)as check_row
    FROM enrollmentCTE c
    INNER JOIN dbo.courseware_master cm ON cm.courseware_id = @courseware_id
    LEFT JOIN @statuscodes s ON s.id = c.enrollment_status_id
    WHERE check_row=1 and 
    enrollment_status_id<>4 and
    rownumber > @firstrow
        AND rownumber < @lastrow
    ORDER BY rownumber
```

`check_row` here is not recognised. Please help

Comment: You need to use a subquery or CTE.  This is standard -- you cannot reference a column alias in a `WHERE` at the same level as the `SELECT` where it is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL order of execution.

> 1. `FROM` clause
> 2. `WHERE` clause
> 3. `GROUP` BY clause
> 4. `HAVING` clause
> 5. `SELECT` clause
> 6. `ORDER BY` clause

the check_row alias was made in the *`select`* part so it doesn't exist yet in the context

**EDIT**
done some testing. can't seem to get it right. as a temporary solution you could  attempt to put the

```
ROW_NUMBER() over(...
```

in the `where` clause aswell

**EDIT:**
another option from the [MSDN website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) is

> Returning a subset of rows
>
> The following example calculates row numbers for all rows in the SalesOrderHeader table in the order of the OrderDate and returns only rows 50 to 60 inclusive.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
WITH OrderedOrders AS
(
    SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate) AS RowNumber
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
) 
SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate, RowNumber  
FROM OrderedOrders 
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 50 AND 60;
```

Comment: aliasing in the from- can you pls elaborate it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT totalRows, ae_effective_enrollment_id, user_id, login_name, first_name, last_name, check_row FROM 
(SELECT TOP (@lastrow - 1) c.totalRows as totalRows 
        ,c.ae_effective_enrollment_id as ae_effective_enrollment_id
        ,c.[user_id] as user_id
        ,c.login_name as login_name
        ,c.first_name as first_name
        ,c.last_name as last_name
        ,cm.courseware_title as courseware_title
        ,cm.courseware_code as courseware_code
        ,@courseware_id as assetId
        ,c.enrollment_status_id as enrollment_status_id
        ,CASE 
            WHEN c.enrollment_status_id = 2
                AND c.is_self_enrolled = 0
                THEN 'Admin-' + s.description
            WHEN c.enrollment_status_id = 2
                AND c.is_self_enrolled = 1
                THEN 'Self-' + s.description
            ELSE s.description
            END AS enrollmentStatus
        ,c.is_group
        ,CASE 
            WHEN c.is_self_enrolled = 0
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END is_admin
        ,CASE 
            WHEN c.auma_is_assigned = 1
                THEN 'Admin-assigned'
            WHEN c.auma_is_assigned = 0
                THEN 'Self-assigned'
            ELSE 'No-My-Plan'
            END AS myplanStatus
        , master_assignment_id
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by cm.courseware_id,c.user_id order by c.is_self_enrolled)as check_row
    FROM enrollmentCTE c
    INNER JOIN dbo.courseware_master cm ON cm.courseware_id = @courseware_id
    LEFT JOIN @statuscodes s ON s.id = c.enrollment_status_id
    WHERE enrollment_status_id<>4 and
    rownumber > @firstrow
        AND rownumber < @lastrow
    ORDER BY rownumber ) t where check_row = 1
```

NOTE - add all column name in first select statement

Answer (score 0):

Use [`CTE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to make your query based on another

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT  c.totalRows
            ,c.ae_effective_enrollment_id
            ,c.[user_id]
            ,c.login_name
            ,c.first_name
            ,c.last_name
            ,cm.courseware_title
            ,cm.courseware_code
            ,@courseware_id assetId
            ,c.enrollment_status_id
            ,CASE 
                WHEN c.enrollment_status_id = 2
                    AND c.is_self_enrolled = 0
                    THEN 'Admin-' + s.description
                WHEN c.enrollment_status_id = 2
                    AND c.is_self_enrolled = 1
                    THEN 'Self-' + s.description
                ELSE s.description
                END AS enrollmentStatus
            ,c.is_group
            ,CASE 
                WHEN c.is_self_enrolled = 0
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END is_admin
            ,CASE 
                WHEN c.auma_is_assigned = 1
                    THEN 'Admin-assigned'
                WHEN c.auma_is_assigned = 0
                    THEN 'Self-assigned'
                ELSE 'No-My-Plan'
                END AS myplanStatus
            , master_assignment_id
            ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by cm.courseware_id,c.user_id order by c.is_self_enrolled) as check_row
    FROM enrollmentCTE c
    INNER JOIN dbo.courseware_master cm ON cm.courseware_id = @courseware_id
    LEFT JOIN @statuscodes s ON s.id = c.enrollment_status_id
    WHERE enrollment_status_id<>4
    AND rownumber > @firstrow
    AND rownumber < @lastrow
)
SELECT TOP (@lastrow - 1) *
FROM CTE
WHERE check_row = 1
ORDER BY rownumber
```